# Bonita jackson Unrecognized token was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: json, business-process-management, bonita

i had created very simple flow i had attached the picture below.

flow description :

> User sends the expense report and finally it gets reviewed and
>   should be approved while i am clicking the approved button. but i was
>   getting error as below :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'onAccept1': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null').
```

current json that i have on variable

```
onAccept1 : return {"comments1" : $data.comments1, "isApproved1":false};
```

can any body please what was the mistake in the json , that i have on the variable called "onAccept1".

[image: my expense report flow]

i got this error while submitting thtask , below was my contract def:
[image]

Comment: When do you get this error message exactly? At the case creation or at the task submission? Also, what is your contract definition on the step where you get the error?

Comment: I got this error while submitting the task ,

Comment: below was the link for my attached bos file , please check this by importing  and let me know i am woirking on this issue from long time , but i did not got big help.    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw_FXgUTZb69UXFiaEw4bnNjMms

Answer (score 0):

Actually you got two different errors in the "Review report1" step form ("newForm12") that prevent successful submission of the form when clicking on "Accept" button.

**First one** is the way the `onAccept1` form variable is bind with the "Accept" button. In your version "Data send on click" property is set with a **constant value** instead of an **expression**. So with the current value set to `onAccept1` means that the value sent will actually be `onAccept1`.
You need to switch from constant to expression by clicking on the "fx" icon on the right of the "Data sent on click" property.

You will switch from [image: Constant]
to [image: expression]

**Second one** is the definition of the `onAccept1` value: you miss the `return` keyword and have quotes around $data value that should not be there. Here is the correct value: `return {"comments1": $data.comments1, "isApproved1": true};`